# Django: multiple different fields -> one model

Tags: django

I want to show different fields (a html-option-field who gets `Mymodel.object.all` and a textfield) and save it to one model field.

How can I build this?

MultiValueField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/) doesn't help with different fields? 
Has someone an example? How can I define which kind of field it is?

EDIT:
How can I determine which field I want to save in the model-field? I use a ModelForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `forms.ModelChoiceField(choices=ModelClass.objects.all())` for the choicefield, you can also set the widget to be `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`.

your form can be like

```
class SuperForm(forms.Form):
    cool_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        choices=ModelClass.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    text_area = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```